# crystal reports multiple pages on single sheet

Tags: crystal-reports, report

i am trying to create a packing slip (about a quarter of a page in size) that i want to be able to print on a single sheet.  IE if i had 3 to print it would print 3 on a single page of paper.  IF i had 7 to print it would print 4 on the first page and 3 on the second.

I have messed around with the columns but that doesn't seem to work the way i had hoped.  I was assuming that i could just create a smaller report (3.5 inches by 4.5) and then print multiple on a page but that didn't work either.

Has anyone done this?

Answer (score 0):

Option 1: turn on the Detail's section '***Format with Multiple Columns***' option.
Option 2: use subreports.

You question doesn't provide enough context to suggest which approach would be better for your use case.